# Error on transaction submission: insufficient funds for gas * price + value - web3 v1+

Tags: web3js

I am trying to submit a transaction via web3 and getting the following error: `Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`.

Here is my code:

```
console.dir(txParams);
const tx = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
       txParams,
       this.hdKey.derive(payment.address.bip32Path)._privateKey
);
this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(tx.rawTransaction);
```

the console statement outputs the following:

> { from: '0xc9d71816ffe465bb682302808f6169ee2B704468',   to:
>   '0x556586125be6e8c3ace675da4fdcb04369ed999d',   gas: '0x5208',
>   gasPrice: '0x4a817c800',   value: '0x10457c59124000' }

The account I am trying to has the requisite ether. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was able to resolve it by changing the format of my private key. The upgraded version of Web3 accepts the key in "0x" format.